# How to have one title in two different languages?

Tags: html, css

I have a website and its content are in two local languages, the problem is that all of the titles are in one language, I want to have titles in both languages animating, 
exp:title1 display for 3 seconds after it then title2 display automatically, I mean one title of two different languages that should be changing to both language.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="cont">
     <h1> title 1 </h1>
     <h1> title 2 </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but is it passable to have pure html and css code?

Comment: I'm happy if I helped you, but what are you going to do with the content ?

Comment: Can't this be done via css only? Something like https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3RotatingWords/ or https://labrumfield.com/rotating-text-with-css-animations/ but usually if you got 2 locales for a site, you use a toggle to toggle between one lang or the other instead of displaying both at the same time. For example, toyota.ca you can view it in french or english

Comment: You can check the browser language and display the local language or a fallback language (English).

Comment: pavelbere actually i have made a project, in this project two local languages are used and every title should be in two languages that's why i need it. thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can achieve this in many ways, using `.slideUp` is just one of them.

```js
$("#1").fadeTo(1000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {
  $("#1").slideUp(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="cont">
    <h1 id="1"> title 1 </h1>
    <h1> title 2 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to apply it to all `h1` you can use `.getElementsByTagName()`, but like i said that will apply it to **all** of them. So i still suggest using the same class on all of them :)

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

$(h1).fadeTo(1000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {
  $(h1).slideUp(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="cont">
    <h1> title 1 </h1>
    <h1> title 2 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Melissa Skywalkz, its fine, but its not animating automatically, i need that every title animate after 2 or 3 second automatically. can you plz help me i will be very thankful.

Comment: I've made another snippet so that you can see what happends if we apply it to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited a bit @Melissa Skywalkz answer
I think you want to swap images continuously

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


function swapImages(){

  var title1 = $('#title1'); 
  var title2 = $('#title2'); 
  if(title1.css("display") == "block")
  {
    title1.slideUp(500); //500 ms animation time 
    title2.slideDown(500);
  }
  else
  {
    title1.slideDown(500);
    title2.slideUp(500);
  }
  
}
   
setInterval(swapImages,3000); // delay between title change
});
```

```css
#title1
{
  display: block;
}
#title2
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h1 id="title1"> title 1 </h1>
    <h1 id="title2"> title 2 </h1>
```

Comment: Great addition! I tried keeping it simple but your answer might be more useful :)

Comment: wow pavelbere exactly i need it, it looks great, i have multiple sections and multiple titles, if i implement this code, i helpless to include every title in the js code as you made it.